# Selecting multiple lines with the snippet manager

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I've been using Ace Editor's Snippet Manager to dynamically insert code for a while, and to select certain text in that insertion. It's been working just fine, but now I've tried to select multiple lines the same way, but it only selects the text in the first line.

How it works: everything within the "`${1:`" and the closing "`}`" should be selected.

This is the code that works. It has multiple lines in it, but only a single line is selected within the curly brackets:

```or-tag-here
var singleStr = "\n<div>\n\t${1:Everything that should be selected is selected}\n</div>\n\n";

insertSingle.addEventListener( 'click', function (evnt) {
    ace.config.loadModule('ace/ext/language_tools', function () {
        editor.insertSnippet( singleStr );
    }); 
});
```

I can't post an image here of the selection working because I don't have enough reputation.

Here's the code that doesn't work. Again there are multiple lines to be inserted, but this time the selection, the text within the curly brackets, contains multiple lines:

```or-tag-here
var insertMulti = document.querySelector('#insert_multi_line');
var multiStr = "<div>\n\t${1:Not everything that should be selected\n\tis selected}\n</div>";

insertMulti.addEventListener( 'click', function (evnt) {
    ace.config.loadModule('ace/ext/language_tools', function () {
        editor.insertSnippet( multiStr );
    }); 
});
```

[multi-line selection not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5z8D.png)

A (not) working example is here (click the buttons to see the different insertions): https://jsfiddle.net/ka7byd8z/3/

I need to be able to do this dynamically with lots of different types of text, which is why I'm using Snippet Manager. How can I insert a snippet with multiple lines selected? Ideally with Snippet Manager or something similar.

Comment: I can verify this is a bug in ace editor, try reporting issue to github

Comment: @a user: Wasn't sure if this was expected/desired behavior or a bug. Issue filed, though I'm not sure this is going to be anyone's top priority. Wish I was experienced enough to fix it myself.